# Next.js Text content does not match server-rendered HTML, useContext

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, rendering

I'm using Next.js static site generation without fetching data in `getStaticProps`. Also using tailwind with `clsx` utility function.

Here is the relevant component:

```js
export const Sidebar = (props: SidebarProps) => {
  const { feedbacks } = useContext(FeedbackContext)

  // returns [{status: 'planned', feedbackCount: 2}, {status: 'live', feedbackCount: 1}, ...]
  const roadmapStatusCount = getRoadmapStatusCount(feedbacks)
  // ...
```

I'm rendering `featureCountElements` based on `roadmapStatusCount`:

```js
const featureCountElements = roadmapStatusCount.map(
  ({ status, feedbackCount }) => {
    return (
      <div key={status}>
        <span
          className={clsx(
            "inline-block h-2 w-2 rounded-full",
            status === "planned" && "bg-accentSecondary",
            status === "in-progress" && "bg-accentPrimary-800",
            status === "live" && "bg-primary-400"
          )}
        ></span>
        <dt className="grow capitalize text-secondary-700">{status}</dt>
        <dd className="font-bold text-secondary-800">{feedbackCount}</dd>
      </div>
    )
  }
)
```

The error says: Warning: Prop `className` did not match. Server: `inline-block h-2 w-2 rounded-full bg-primary-400` Client: `inline-block h-2 w-2 rounded-full bg-accentPrimary-800`. Background value changed. This means that for some reason one of the status values was different or perhaps elements rendered in different order?

The context looks like this. The initial value `productRequests` comes from a local, static JSON file.

```
interface IFeedbackContext {
  feedbacks: Feedback[]
  setFeedbacks: Dispatch<SetStateAction<Feedback[]>> | null
}

export const FeedbackContext = createContext<IFeedbackContext>({
  feedbacks: productRequests,
  setFeedbacks: null
})
```

I'm uncertain about server side vs client side rendering in this case. What is the issue here? This wasn't a problem until I introduced `useContext` hook.

Comment: where status is coming from ? you usually get this kind of errors when using local storage / cookies

Comment: State is coming from `_app.tsx` where I fill it with initial value (local json file object) and wrap page components with a provider.

Comment: I misread, the status is coming from `getRoadmapStatusCount` function, which filters elements based on `feedbacks` that was passed in. I have a code example above.

Comment: does Next.Js has access to the same json file when rendering ? also, do you use useEffect somewhere by any chance ?

Comment: Not sure, since it's a local json file and I'm not using `getStaticProps`, I don't think Next.js has access to it... But it still renders element with a background color (one of the status matched/obj is filled). How can I test server version of the data? Not using useEffect.

Comment: Also, this wasn't a problem when I was *not* using useContext.

Comment: I'm a bit lost here sorry. when you say a local json file, you mean that you `import 'whatever.json'` right ?

Comment: Well, it's an exported json object, not a json file itself (I forgot to mention this). `export const myData = {...}`

Comment: just to recap your error here. Next is saying that the server version (Node.JS) doesn't map the client version (Web). Also, server side does NOT run useAction() hooks as they are supposed to run only on frontend.

Comment: How does the span still get a very specific background color *on the server* then (according to the error message)? It only gets `bg-primary-400` if the status "live" matches. useAction hooks do not run on the server, but what is the fallback? Is there a way to see what the server data looks like?